# Не работает отправка сообщения в сообщество

Tags: vkontakte-api

Есть такой всем известный код, и он работает:

```
$url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send';
$params = array(
    'user_id' => $id,    // Кому отправляем
    'message' => $message,   // Что отправляем
    'access_token' => '0000000000000000000000000000',  // access_token можно вбить хардкодом, если работа будет идти из под одного юзера
    'v' => '5.37',
);

// В $result вернется id отправленного сообщения
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query($params)
    )
)));
```

но отправляет сообщение пользователю, а мне нужно отправить сообщение в группу (сообщество).
Гугл говорит что для этого нужно поменять всего две вещи:
Выпустить токен для сообщества, и вбить вместо юзер-токена.
И вместо id юзера, прописать peer_id(?) со знаком "-".
Условно говоря, как-то так:

```
'peer_id' => '-207788703',
            'message' => $this->getMessageVk($message),
            'access_token' => '5f4f651886b9077f6715bc6b',
            'v' => '5.73',
```

Но... не работает.

```
{"error":{
  "error_code":901,
  "error_msg":"Can't send messages for users without permission",
  "request_params":[
    {"key":"method","value":"messages.send"},
    {"key":"oauth","value":"1"},
    {"key":"peer_id","value":"-207788703"},
    {"key":"v","value":"5.81"}
  ]
}}
```

А где этот permission указать в настройках?

Comment: Какую ошибку возвращает ВК в ответе на ваш запрос?

Comment: Не знаю как сделать вывод ошибок.
В мануале ВК только коды самих ошибок, без примеров :(

Comment: Эм, просто `echo $result;` наверное?

Comment: Конечно ))

{"error":{"error_code":901,"error_msg":"Can't send messages for users without permission","request_params":[{"key":"method","value":"messages.send"},{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"peer_id","value":"-207788703"},{"key":"v","value":"5.81"}]}}
А где этот permission указать в настройках?